# An adjective for "censorship" when it is really strong

Tags: single-word-requests

> In this country Internet censorship is quite _____. The government censors 80 percent of websites.

I have several things in mind but the best to me seem to be "[**drastic**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/thesaurus/drastic)", "[**intense**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/thesaurus/intense)", or "[**high**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/high)" (Oxford Dictionaries and Thesaurus). What would be an idiomatic option when describing extreme [**Internet censorship**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_censorship)? (Wikipedia) What would be most sensible to my reader and have the most impact in the above example?

(Note that I have edited the content and order of the sentences from the original posting in response to comments and answers received.)

Comment: Hmm. *Redacts*? It has a better sense of overbearing government censorship, but it’s usually applied to obscuring specific words or texts in a given document.

Comment: Oh, I see now. You’re not looking for a word for censorship, the blank is at the end of your quoted passage. You want a general word for *severity*. Ok, how about ***draconian***? Fits the context nicely.

Comment: @DanBron Yes a word relevant for censorship, like "drastic censorship". Is draconian idiomatic in "draconian censorship"?

Comment: Idiomatic, I think, is a red herring. It’s perfectly natural, but it’s not a set phrase or common pairing. For your purpose, you don’t want a common pairing; you want to make an *impact*. To use some hackneyed phrase would be counterproductive. It’s an intensifier (in the vernacular not grammatical sense) here. And yes, *draconian* carries connotations of extreme and bureaucratic overreach. For that reason, it’s often applied to government actions or in related contexts. Worth looking up the etymology, btw, really interesting.

Comment: That said, if you’re really after the most common collocations for [“*adj* censorship”, here’s analysis from the COCA](https://corpus.byu.edu/coca/?c=coca&q=70011571) (so, using American writing specifically). If that link doesn’t work for you, [here’s a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bODLg.png). The top few words which have your sense of “strict” are: *strict* (#1 most frequent), *heavy*, *outright*, *overt*, and *imposing* (though this last might be in contexts meaning “the act of”, not “strict”, but it works for both). But I think this list demonstrates what I’m saying: “meh” words.

Comment: @DanBron Thanks for the source. Would you please let me know what "_j*" mean? Couldn't find it in the guide.

Comment: That's the notation for the specific collocation search. I believe, but I am not sure, that it breaks down into location (`_`) which is an adjective (`j`) followed by the collocated word (`*`).  But that notation was added automatically for me as I used the UI elements configure my search ("*censorship preceded immediately by an adjective"), using dropdowns and such.  I'm sure the notation is documented somewhere on the BYU site, but I've never had to use it. I just use the widgets, and so far, it's met all my needs.

Comment: You should also be aware that [BYU has several other searchable corpora](https://corpus.byu.edu/), which help focus searches on specific writing communities (American English, British English, contemporary writing on the web, early English books, etc etc etc).  It's well worth the stunning $0 fee to sign up.

Comment: THANK YOU for the link to the BYU corpora, Dan. I was not aware of their existence.

Comment: @MarkHubbard Yes, they're great! Invaluable for finding evidence of usage and identifying collocations.  Especially for rarer items. I actually used one yesterday to find an attestation that [antedates OED's earliest by *three centuries*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/470068/what-is-the-origin-of-prepone-in-indian-english#comment1135000_470101).

Comment: perhaps "heavy-handed"

Comment: A word or phrase request can easily attract a long list of answers when it’s too subjective – more of a poll or request for ideas. Unfortunately neither are a good fit for the Stack Exchange model. A Stack Exchange question is objective and specific enough that it has a clearly “right” answer. See: “[Real questions have answers, not items or ideas or opinions](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/17/real-questions-have-answers/)”, “[Single word requests, crosswords, and the fight against mediocrity](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2160)”.

Comment: @MetaEd Seriously? 10 up-votes for the question, 10 answers for it, 36 users consider one answer useful, 11 and 7 for next answers. And, you, one single person, think it is too subjective, and put it on hold?

Comment: @Sasan Don't sweat it.  You got plenty of good answers! Which is all that matters, it's why you asked. You also got points, if those matter to you (though I don't recommend assigning any value to them).  I have an answer here with an 800-something score, on a question with a 400-something score, and a dozen other highly-voted answers, and it's historically locked (not identical to closure but the results are the same). It happens to all of us. Let's enjoy what we got out of it, rather than fight the tides.

Comment: @Sasan This is not the place to dispute moderation policy. A welcoming place for any kind of open discussion is our [English Language & Usage Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95).

Comment: @MetaEd This question was closed for not meeting the SWR "example sentence" requirement, even though an example sentence *had* been provided. I've edited it to leave no doubt that it meets our site's requirements, and closure is no longer appropriate.

Comment: @Chappo There is more to the SWR tag than the example sentence requirement. Any question needs to be objective and specific enough that it can have a clearly right answer. When a question attracts a long list of ideas, the question is either subjective (and does not belong on SE) or just unclear (and can be reopened after the question is clarified).

Comment: @Chappo The SWR tag gives detailed information about what is needed to make an SWR objective and specific enough: details of research already done, especially solutions you’ve already rejected, and why; the desired connotation, register (formality), part of speech, and context in which it is to be used; and, as you've pointed out, the exact enclosing sentence or passage.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

"**draconian"** seems to fit perfectly.

The government censors 80 percent of websites. Internet censorship is draconian in this country.

> - [**draconian**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/draconian) laws or measures are extremely harsh and severe.
> - Draconian is an adjective meaning great severity, that derives from Draco, an Athenian law scribe under whom small offenses had heavy punishments (Draconian laws).
>   From [**Wikipedia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Draconian)

[**Etymology**](https://www.etymonline.com/word/draconian) - draconian (adj.)
1759, "of or pertaining to Draco," the ancient Greek statesman; 1777, in reference to laws, "rigorous, extremely severe or harsh" (earlier Draconic, which is implied from 1640s). Draco is the Latinized form of Greek Drakon, name of the archon of Athens who laid down a code of laws for Athens c. 621 B.C.E. that mandated death as punishment for minor crimes. His name seems to mean literally "sharp-sighted" (see dragon).

> - [**Draco**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Draco_(lawgiver)) was the first recorded legislator of Athens in Ancient Greece. He replaced the prevailing system of oral law and blood feud by a written code to be enforced only by a court of law. Draco was the first democratic legislator, he was requested by the Athenian citizens to be a lawgiver for the city-state, but the citizens were fully unaware that Draco would establish harsh laws. Draco's written law was characterized by its harshness. To this day, the adjective draconian refers to similarly unforgiving rules or laws, in English and other European languages.

Comment: Not only does draconian fit, but "harsh" and "severe" are also great fits in the OP's sentence IMHO - possibly more idiomatic.  To me, "draconian" implies severity *above and beyond* mere censorship, but that's an issue perhaps of connotations rather than definitions.  While on the subject, I'd also expect to hear "draconian" applied to "censorship laws" rather than just "censorship" itself, but that may be simply my own biased opinion based on very little as far as evidence.  The meaning is no doubt perfectly clear regardless.

Comment: I'd argue that draconian generally refers to the *punishment* being severe, not the extent of the legislation.  If the government cuts off your fingers for posting objectionable material then yeah, I'm good with calling it draconian.  Here, it just seems like they're being a little overzealous.

Comment: You beat me to it @AC. I don't like draconian here. Heavy-handed would be a better choice IMO.

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=draconian+censorship&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdraconian%20censorship%3B%2Cc0

Comment: So the name Draco Malfoy is rather suitable for the character in Harry Potter ;-)

Answer (score 12):

[**Orwellian**](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/132902?redirectedFrom=orwellian#eid), after the Ministry of Truth in the novel *1984*:

> **A.** adj. Characteristic or suggestive of the writings of George Orwell, esp. of the totalitarian state depicted in his dystopian account of the future, *Nineteen Eighty-four* (1949).

[**Totalitarian**](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/203795?redirectedFrom=totalitarian#eid) could work as well:

> **A.** adj. Of or pertaining to a system of government which tolerates only one political party, to which all other institutions are subordinated, and which usually demands the complete subservience of the individual to the State.

Comment: I was halfway through writing an answer with "totalitarian" when I noticed it was in your post, so I've taken the liberty of putting in an edit request to add reference and definitions for you. In the future though, it'd help if you put them in your post when you post it.

Comment: "Orwellian" has acquired a meaning of "hypocrisy", from such institutions as the Ministry of Peace being in charge of war.

Comment: @Acccumulation I think it’s more an implication of bald-faced lying. Although really it’s often used against political opponents as a vague, inchoate insult. It always implies, though, that someone is authoritatively declaring the opposite of the truth to be true and trying to intimidate everyone else into accepting it.

Answer (score 8):

Your question was, "What would be an idiomatic option?" as to how to finish the sentence

> "The government censors 80 percent of websites. In this country the Internet censorship is quite ....?"

I suggest "[**severe**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/severe)" (Merriam-Webster) for a single-word answer:

> strict in judgment, discipline, or government; rigorous in restraint, punishment, or requirement.

Otherwise, your construction (as currently edited with the order of statements reversed) is idiomatic and good English. I would prefer to combine the two sentences into one:

> In this country Internet censorship is severe: the government blocks
>    access to 80 percent of websites.

This [source](https://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/colons.asp), for instance, explains that

> A colon instead of a semicolon may be used between independent clauses when the second sentence explains, illustrates, paraphrases, or expands on the first sentence.

However, stating it as two sentences is perfectly acceptable.

---

By the way, I love the word "draconian" (and up-voted the answer by @Centaurus as well), but depending on your audience it may not be as readily understandable (and therefore not as idiomatic) as a more common term like "severe."

Comment: While this is probably the way I'd write it too, this doesn't really answer the question, and should probably be a comment.

Comment: "Severe" is also what sprung to my mind as far as being idiomatic.

Comment: @Michael Seifert: Thank you for your comment. I hope my revisions have made my answer more acceptable.

Answer (score 6):

> The government censors 80 percent of websites. In this country the Internet
> censorship is quite ....?

First point... should take out a 'the' to give

> The government censors 80 percent of websites. In this country Internet
> censorship is quite ....?

I think Draconian is excellent as suggested in the accepted answer.

Other alternatives include

> pervasive

pervasive means that it is something you find everywhere and is very difficult to get away from. For example, mobile phones are quite pervasive in society.

> extreme
>
> heavy-handed

or

> The government censors 80 percent of websites. In this country Internet
> censorship is brutal.

and I agree with the answer that it is better to swap the order of these two sentences

Comment: +1 for heavy handed or brutal.

Answer (score 3):

I think the punishment that befalls the people who are censored is relevant here. If offending sites are merely blocked, that's bad enough but if the people who wrote the material are imprisoned or executed, that is clearly worse. "Draconian" seems appropriate if the authors are imprisoned but "widespread" or "rampant" may be sufficient if there is no punishment beyond blocking the site. If authors are executed, I might use "murderous" or "Stalinist" to invoke the repressions faced by people who ran afoul of the Communist Party in Stalin's day.

Answer (score 3):

When I think of a government enacting laws in order to enforce what it thinks is best for the people or for the maintenance of social morality and integrity, I think of “**paternalism**”, adjective “paternalistic”.

> **paternalism**
>  *n* (Government, Politics & Diplomacy) the attitude or
>   policy of a government or other authority that manages the affairs of
>   a country, company, community, etc, in the manner of a father, esp in
>   usurping individual responsibility and the liberty of choice
>   [Collins English Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/paternalism)
>
> *Paternalism* is action limiting a person's or group's liberty or
>   autonomy which is intended to promote their own good.
>  [Wikipedia
>   article on paternalistic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paternalism)

"paternalistic" could fit in your sentence, as in:

> In this country the Internet censorship is quite paternalistic.

However I think, using this word, it would sound better as:

> The government censors 80 percent of websites. Its censorship policies
>   reflect **a highly paternalistic mode** of governance.

Answer (score 2):

I would use the word "egregious."

> e·gre·gious /əˈɡrējəs/Submit adjective
>   1. outstandingly bad; shocking. "egregious abuses of copyright" synonyms: shocking, appalling, terrible, awful, horrendous, frightful,
>   atrocious, abominable, abhorrent, outrageous; More

Answer (score 1):

I would use **suppressive**.

To me, draconian suggests harsh punishment. I wouldn't consider censorship to be draconian.

> In this country Internet censorship is quite suppressive. The
>   government censors 80 percent of websites.

Suppress (from Merriam Webster)

> 1 : to put down by authority or force
>
> 2 : to keep from public knowledge: such as
>
> ```
> a : to keep secret
>
> b : to stop or prohibit the publication or revelation of suppress the test results
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Authoritarian
Favouring or enforcing strict obedience to authority at the expense of personal freedom.

Draconian seems to suggest punishment. Authoritarian suggests controlling rather than punishing

Comment: If you quote words directly from a dictionary, you **must** cite the source, otherwise it is **plagiarism**. Please [edit] your answer to include the name of the dictionary and preferably a link to the definition.

Comment: For further guidance, see [this Meta post on proper attribution](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9602) :-)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to considering draconian as suggested by several other posters, perhaps "robust" or "profound" could work if suggesting that the censorship is severe as in far-reaching or very prolific.